# OAuth 2 three-legged authentication against a third-party API

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

Generally speaking this is not a ASP.NET Core question but that's the framework my web app is built on.

The flow is:

1. User logs into my application against my own AD.
2. All the application APIs are accessible with the token received from the AD.
3. At some point the user *may* need data from a third-party API that's secured by three-legged authentication. The user account used in this API is not the same as in my own AD.
4. The user goes through the authorization process for the external API and a token for it is received.

Points #1-2 are already covered in my implementation.

How do I set up this authorization for this kind of a scenario? There's a token from my AD that is used to grant access to my own APIs but the also the third-party token that is only needed to access their APIs.

I don't know if my Googling skills are too weak but I haven't been able to find resources on this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is a third party dependency.

Create an API to interact with that dependency or a wrapper if you'd like.

That API will internally contain all the sensitive information needed to interact with the 3rd party API.

You can secure this API just like you secured others. In essence your API will use the Client Credential flow to interact with the 3rd party.